# Get friends who interacted on timeline - Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to get **list of friends who likes my post on my timeline since 1st Jan, 16 and the story's privacy set to FRIENDS**. So I tried this Graph API but I'm getting list of profiles which included friends and some non-friends profile too !
I want to get only the friends profile list.

```
me/posts?fields=likes{name},privacy=ALL_FRIENDS&since=2016-01-01
```

**The main target is to create possible friends list without taggable or invite API**

Comment: Is it documented anywhere that you can use `privacy=ALL_FRIENDS` to filter the results? Or is that just wishful thinking on your part?

Comment: I just thought it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If the privacy is set to friends, you should only get friends. There is no way to check if someone is a friend, unless that friends authorized your App too. In that case, he would show up in the `/me/friends` endpoint.

I can only think of one reason why you would get more than just friends: If you tagged a friend, the friends of the tagged user would see the post too.

If that is not the case, you may file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Nope. My posts have no tagged profile. But still getting non-friend profiles.

Comment: i tested the api call and only got friend likes. if you are sure that there are likes from non-friends, you should really file a bug.

Comment: I've filed a bug. Thnx for the valuable info :)

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing 'non-friends' with 'a user who wasn't in the response to a call to /me/friends'? The latter contains only the users' friends who have also logged into your app